# Laravel Inertia Active Route - Prefix Wildcard (React/Named Routes)

Tags: laravel, routes, inertiajs

```
 <NavLink
                                    href={route("dashboard")}
                                    active={route().current("dashboard")}
                                >
                                    Your Dashboard
                                </NavLink>
```

This works great for the page, however I've grouped routes with prefixes. I want to check it against the parent prefix of the route. How could I modify this?

Thank you.